# Cleaning row names in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data-set in excel spreadsheet where the row-names are duplicates or near-duplicates, like shown in the image below. Is there a 'tidy' way (in R) of cleaning this? Even a partial solution like merging different rows with different cases (upper, lower, sentence) would be much appreciated.

[image: image of a few rows of the dataset showing the duplicate city names]

I am familiar with clean_names (e.g. https://rpubs.com/jenrichmond/clean_names) but I was not able to find one that does this specific job. I want to create another data-frame where I have just one row for each unique city name.

Comment: Different cases is easy - convert them all to the same case and do a grouped sum: `your_data |> rownames_to_column("name") |> mutate(name = tolower(name)) |> summarize(Count = sum(Count), .by = name))`. Correcting typos like `ABILENE` vs `ABLIENE` is quite a bit more difficult - it's called "fuzzy deduplication" and [this is a pretty good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74368289/903061) / potential duplicate for that part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# the issue with the code below is that we get the error: duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
rownames(df) <- rownames(df) |> tolower()

# so as Gregor states, we need to create a new column for the rownames, and then we can go from there:

library(tidyverse)

df <- df |>
  mutate(Name = rownames(df) |> str_to_title()) |>
  summarise(Count = sum(Count), .by = Name)
```

In the code above, you can change str_to_title() to str_to_lower() or str_to_upper() depending on what case you want

To match typos, you can use the fuzzyjoin package, with its stringdist_*join() functions:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

good_df <- data.frame(
    Town = c("Abbott", "Abernathy", "Abilene"))

good_df |> 
  stringdist_left_join(df, by = c("Town" = "Name"), max_dist = 2) |>
  summarise(Count = sum(Count), .by = Town)
```

Output:

```
       Town Count
1    Abbott     0
2 Abernathy    37
3   Abilene   876
```

The stringdist join functions can be a bit janky in my experience,
not having 100% accuracy, so you end up a decent amount of time
playing around with the different methods and the parameters, and
then later have to to go through manually and fix the ones whichdidn't work. You might be better off if your dataset is large in creating a dataframe with a typo name column, and a real name column, and join on your dataset.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Count = c(104L, 0L, 37L, 2L, 2L, 872L, 0L)), row.names = c("", 
"ABBOTT", "ABERNATHY", "abilene", "Abilene", "ABILENE", "ABLIENE"
), class = "data.frame")
```